# CWebDriverTestCase by SeleniumTestCasr

Tags: selenium, yii, yii-extensions

I am trying Yii Selenium unit testing. How can I manage confirm box in that?
Which method is used to get alert message text?

Answer (score 0):

PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase provides

```
void assertAlertPresent()    Reports an error if no alert is present.
void assertNoAlertPresent()  Reports an error if an alert is present.
```

For managing alerts, you can use methods from Selenium API
http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html

```
storeAlert()
chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation()
chooseOkOnNextConfirmation()
```

P.S. Selenium tests are functional, not unit